# Can you destroy the rebels in Rome Total War?

Tags: rome-total-war

How can you destroy the rebel empire? I have taken over forts, armies and destroyed navies. There is only one more faction left (Brittania) and they have the last territory. Do the rebels continue to fight even though they have no armies or civilians to fight with?

Comment: They aren't an empire. They're more of a "None of the above" and they're not allied with anyone, up to and including themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot destroy the Rebel faction in the way that you can destroy normal factions.

Generally, a faction is destroyed if they lose all of their settlements or if all of the  men in the family die.

The Rebels are not destroyed. They represent forces and settlements not allied to any of the major factions. It may be possible to eliminate all Rebel forces and settlements on the map, but more Rebels could appear later.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the rebels are not allied with each other. There are many factions of *rebels*. Also, they can exist without any family members (unlike all other factions).

Answer (score -2):

Destroying rebels is hard. Rebels cause problems. they can take over a town that you have taken mostly those towns near ports. so keep them away by strengthening these towns with large armies mostly the cavalries

Comment: That's good, but you're not really answering the question at all.  CAN the rebels be destroyed?